# How do I add subnets and VLANS into my network

Tags: subnet, vlan

First let me say I have posted this on cisco support forums and just copied and pasted into a new question for you here. Secondly I think I understand that to route through subnets I need a router between each subnet with a unique IP address for each subnet on each router. please correct me if I'm wrong. Thirdly I think I understand that I need a router to communicate between vlans on different subnets. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And thirdly to communicate between vlans on the same subnet all I need is a layer 2 switch between vlans. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now here's my post to cisco community from today that I just copied and pasted here. Please help out with any corrections, ideas, and comments on how to do what I want to do. I hope I have the whole concept down.

Hello Friends.

I have a scenario that i'm hoping i can get some help with. I'll be as detailed and descriptive as i can.

This is for a business with 100 employees nodes and 100 camera nodes all needing IP internet through private addressing and public gateway.

I have a business class gateway with a private range of 12 public addresses. Ther modem does nothing but act as a gateway since i have disabled the firewall and DHCP.

In place of the firewall and DCHP from the modem i have installed a RV120 Firewall with VPN. When installing i replicated the IP scheme of the modem as to not disturb and distrup the devices assigned addresses from that scheme from the modem. I did this because the owner could not have any down time or any disruption to the business operations.

The RV120 now acts as firewall , DHCP , and VPN. I'll address the subnet first. I's using 10.0.0.0/24 subnet range.

DHCP is assigning 10.1.10.50 - 10.1.10.100 the rest are static and i plan to use static DHCP with the IP and MAC assigned to each static DHCP address.

There are 100 cameras with static IP addresses in the range of 10.1.10.11 - 10.1.10.40, and 10.1.0.1.101 - 10.1.10.170.

VPN uses PPTP assigned address 10.1.10.6 - 10.1.10.10.

There are no layer 3 switches that i know of. Just a layer two that is the primary swith and ports have run out, and various out of the box switches and wireless access points connected to the primary switch.

I want to implement subnets into the network and VLANS as well on a new Layer 3 switche from cisco. Thinking 3550 from Cisco or one of the older layer 2 switches with layer three capabilities.

I also want to introduce a 192.168.0.0/24 IP range for the existing wireless network and segment the traffic from the rest of the traffic on other ranges.

I want to replace the 10.0.0.0/24 DHCP alltogether and the static addresses for end user nodes on the same network, but keep that range just for camera nodes segmented.

I want to implement a NEW end user IP range and VLAN for employee/guest networks using the 172.16.0.0/24 range.

Iv'e thought of replacing all the wireless nodes with RV120's and use VLAN. Dont know if that strategy works. Need to think it through.

I want the 192.168.0.0/24 IP range comunicate to with the 172.16.0.0/24 and possibly the 10.0.0.0/24 range.

Any advice on how to do this?

As a side note the next step after this is to install a server domain controller as all the computers are all stand alones in their own workgroups. It's a simultaneous project that will introdue a DCHP, WINS, DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a router or a layer 3 switch to make those networks communicate between themselves.

In case of layer 3 switches you need to create a "vlan interface" and configure it with an ip address, for each of your networks.

These ip addresses will need to be the gateways from each of the networks.